# How to determine the underlying provider used by Antimalware Scan Interface?

Tags: antivirus, malware-detection, windows-server-2019, windows-security

Is there a easy way to see which underlying malware provider is handling the requests for [Antimalware Scan Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/amsi/antimalware-scan-interface-portal)?  Win32 call or registry key?

Windows Server 2019

Answer (score 2):

According to MSFT [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/amsi/dev-audience#register-your-provider-dll-with-amsi), appears there are two registry keys for finding this info:

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AMSI\Providers
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID